# Extract letters from file

Tags: java, file

I have a question on how to extract letters from File. This is an example line from the file I read.

ui     Parker       8

I read 3 tokens and am supposed to extract 2 letters from the first token but not sure how to do it. The code references 5 attributes which are part of an object that was declared earlier and 3 tokens in the file. The first letter determines if the student is undergraduate or graduate and the second letter determines if the student is instate or out of state.

```
  while(fileScan.hasNext())
           {

            classStatus = fileScan.next();

            if(classStatus.charAt(0) == 'u' || classStatus.charAt(0) == 'U')
            {
                classStatus= "underGrad";
            }
            else
            {
                classStatus= "Grad";
            }

            studentName = fileScan.next();
            resident = fileScan.next();


            numberOfCredits = fileScan.nextInt();
            double tuitionBill = fileScan.nextDouble();


            StudentNode aNode = new StudentNode(classStatus,studentName,resident);
```

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please provide more information what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am supposed to read 3 tokens from the file. First token contains 2 letters "ui" which is undergraduate and instate. So my question is how to extract 2 letters from 1 token so then i can test if/else

Comment: Please spare us your life story and provide example input and expected output.

Comment: @Bohemian that cracked me up.

Answer (score 0):

So an important part left out is you are using `java.lang.Scanner` (the type of fileScan) yeah?

Well, because your file is most likely well organized:

token [space] token [space] token

you can read each line in as a String and then effectively do a split on spaces on each line read in.  With `Scanner` we can accomplish this split through regular expressions, more specifically by using the `useDelimiter()` method.  A good reference is [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935854/parse-text-using-scanner-usedelimiter) for using `useDelimiter()`.

Anyway, to continue, you use `fileScan.next()` to get each token as a String.  Then you use the `substring` method or `charAt` method like above to pick out the necessary characters.